# Does the `getSObjects` method on `SObject` work with Person Account child relationships?

Tags: sobject, dynamic-soql, person-accounts

Our app uses a lot of dynamic SOQL, and in a client org I'm currently getting an error which I can't explain when we're performing a large query against account, including subqueries for all related lists on the page layout.

I've boiled it down to this (ignore line breaks in the string, just added them for readability):

```
String q = 'SELECT OwnerId,
    (SELECT Name FROM Conversations__pr LIMIT 5)
    FROM Account WHERE Id = \'abc123467890abc\'';

SObject queryResult = Database.query(q);
System.Debug(queryResult.getSObjects('Conversations__pr'));
```

`Conversation__c` is an object configured by the client that has a lookup to Contact, hence it should be available via a child relationship with the suffix `__pr` from Account:

[image: Dev console query tool results]

### AND YET!

if I run the above code via Execute Anonymous in the dev console, I get this:

> Line: 10, Column: 1
>   System.SObjectException: SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: Account.Conversations__r

My code definitely does not use `'Conversations__r'`, so I suspect there's a platform bug at play here.

### Further Findings

If I change `queryResult` to be an instance of `Account` rather than `SObject`, then `queryResult.Conversations__pr` returns the data expected, but no, I can't change the code to that because this does need to be dynamic. I can't find any references to this kind of issue with `getSObjects`, so am I doing something dumb that I can't see or is this a bug?

Answer (score 9):

Ok, I'm guessing Salesforce might hide their known issues from being crawled by search engines. Typed in `getSObjects` into the success community and the first thing that appeared was a known issue describing exactly this scenario:

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000SvzXAAS

Apparently this has been reported by zero users, but maybe because there's no "This issue affects me" box at the top of the screen as there should be because it's a "No Fix" bug. That's just great.

> No Fix - Salesforce Engineering Management determined that a fix for the issue is not possible.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't even know Contact relationships could be traversed from Person Account SOQL this way. FWIW I tried the same thing out in a client sandbox I have that uses Person Accounts. I wanted to see if I could get clever and use `getPopulatedFieldsAsMap` or `JSON.serialize`. Neither one seems to work on Contact child relationships. So perhaps your best bet is just, any `PersonSomethings` or `__pr` child relationships should just be queried separately via the Contact object. At least that is something you can do dynamically enough.

Comment: Yeah it's a bit of a pain, but I'll have to separate out those relationships, run the other query and then put it all back together into a cohesive whole again.

Comment: I wonder what their special hack is. Maybe at compile time, references to person child relationships are transformed into something else.

Comment: Having hit this again (I'd forgotten about it in the mean time until I tried to fix the same problem as before) I just took the dumb route and if automatically try and query the contact direct for each relationship that fails on the account.

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that the base problem is still at issue (`getSObjects` doesn't work for person child relationships).

BUT something changed in `SObject.getPopulatedFieldsAsMap()`!

```
Id i = '0016g000002q1OWAAY';
String s = 'SELECT Id, (SELECT Id, Name FROM CustomSamples__pr) FROM Account WHERE Id = :i';
Account[] accts = Database.query(s);    
Account a = accts[0];
Map<String, Object> smap = a.getPopulatedFieldsAsMap();
Object ochildren = smap.get('CustomSamples__pr');
List<CustomSample__c> samples = (List<CustomSample__c>)ochildren;
System.debug(samples);
```

This works now for me in a fresh trial org with Person Accounts just enabled. I get my child list safe and sound. So there is now a workaround: Instead of `getSObjects`, use `getPopulatedFieldsAsMap`, get from the correct child relationship key, and cast to a list of SObjects.

Comment: Will try and check that this works before I change the accepted answer, but you definitely get my upvote, and hopefully I'll find sometime in the next week to verify it!

Comment: TBH I have no idea how reproducible it is across orgs. But basically I just finished writing a managed package that, in part, parses out all the data it can find in a dynamic SOQL query through recursive use of `getPopulatedFieldsAsMap`. At design time, over a year ago, I tested code like the above and it did NOT work. Today, for a lark, I tested our UAT version of the package in a Person Accounts org and was baffled that it actually found on the Person child data. Tested this code again and it works now. So strange.

Comment: I'm intruiged to try it. Could deifnitely be the author of `getPopulatedFieldsAsMap` was just a little more thorough than the dev original dev of `getSObjects` :)

Comment: Perhaps the SOQL to Apex engine got a bump in recent versions because polymorphic SOQL went GA?